# Number of mosquitos in an area ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, the question is:

The rate of growth of some population of mosquitoes in a certain area is proportional to the number of mosquitoes. Without natural predators, the populations **doubles** every week. In the beginning, there are $200 000$ mosquitoes in this area, but birds eat $20000$ mosquitoes every day.
Determine the number of mosquitoes at any given moment $t$.

So, we usually did this by setting an ODE.

If $N$ is the number of mosquitoes, then $$\frac{dN}{dt}=kN$$
and $N_0=200000$, but I'm unsure how to actually use the other two conditions, i.e. birds eat $20000$ mosquitoes every day and the number of mosquitoes doubles every week without natural predators.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

$$N(t+h)=N(t)2^h-7\cdot20000h $$

$$\frac{N(t+h)-N(t)}{h}=N(t)\frac{(2^h-1)}{h}-7\cdot20000 $$

Then take $\lim _{h \to 0}(\cdot)$

$$N'(t)=N(t)\log2-140000$$

Comment: @windircurse: I gave practically the same answer as C.Hegg with some additional explanation and I answered one day earlier. Why didn't you accept my answer?

Comment: you're right, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create the full ODE that describes this dynamic and solve it. Without any external forces the equation you have is correct, which has a solution $N(t)=N_0e^{\lambda t}$ (where t is measured in days). With the info given, we can figure out what lambda is. Initially, $N(0)=N_0$, then 7 days later, $N(7)=2N_0=N_0e^{\lambda *7}$. So $\lambda=\frac{ln(2)}{7}$. Now the ODE with predation can be wrote as:

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=\lambda N-predation.$$ 
The predation term is already given as a rate. So you ODE should be
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=\lambda N-20000.$$ With initial condition $N(0)=N_0=200000$. This equation is easily solved as it is separable.

Comment: @CHegg: You can't guess the form of the differential equation, you have to prove it.

Comment: @Tomi27: Sorry, what do you have to prove? The ODE describes the dynamics exactly and the solution gives the number of mosquitos at time $t$.

Comment: @CHegg: I would show why the ODE has the form what you use, but OK, maybe it's not necessary.